# Shape gradient not smooth on some devices

Tags: android, gradient, android-shapedrawable

I'm trying to add gradient above text using `ShapeDrawable`. The goal is to fade text on the left and right side of the screen. The layout is following:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/text_view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text_view"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_shape"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view"
        android:background="#00f"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/line"
        android:background="#f00"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Gradient `ShapeDrawable`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#ffffffff"
    android:endColor="#00ffffff"
    android:type="linear"
    />

</shape>
```

The problem is that on my `HTC Desire` HD gradient is not smooth. On screen it looks like this: (sorry for the quality, image is slightly adjusted in photo editor to make the effect more visible)

[image: gradient photo]

I figured out, that this line in gradient appears at the center of gradient drawable. Blue line below gradient shows this. 
Can any one suggest me how to fix this? On device this looks bad.

I've tried to run this app on emulator and `Ritmix-RMP-470` - everything looks fine. Gradient is smooth and beauty. But on `HTC Desire` HD the problem exists.
Also, I've tried to take screenshot from device using `DDMS`. On screenshot everything looks fine too:

[image: gradient screenshot using ddms]

I event tried to make gradient `PNG` image in photo editor and then use this `png` instead of `ShapeDrawable`. The result is still the same.

Any way to avoid this visual problem with gradient?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    ...
}
```

Some phones (especially HTC) use another defaul PixelFormat. It doesn't show for clean color surfaces but anything that is gradient or with shadow will simply look wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help. But thanks anyway.